# MKPointAnnotation add extra property

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkpointannotation

Is it possible to add an extra property to `MKPointAnnotation`? At the moment there is `coordinate`, `title`, and `subtitle`.

Is it possible to add a `url` property which can be accessed within `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{ }`, just like I can access`[annotation title];`?

Answer (score 5):

Just make an `MKPointAnnotation` subclass.

Delete all the methods out of the `.m` file, and add this to your `.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
```

Comment: Hi @undo thanks for this. Are there any good resources on the net for this? New to the language

Comment: @JoshBoothe I think [this](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/classes.html) might be a good read for you.

Comment: thanks for that, looking at it, I need the `MKPinAnnotationView` not `MKPointAnnotation` though?

Comment: @JoshBoothe Whatever you want placed on your map is what you want to subclass.